# Handling nested Maybe monad inside Future

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

I'm still getting the hang of Functional Programming and am trying to figure out a bit of a curly issue with Monads. I have a situation where I have a future that makes an HTTP request and returns a list of values, for argument's sake. I then want to be able to check that a particular value exists in that list, I would have thought returning a Maybe monad here would be the win. But then if that value is present I want to be able to make another HTTP request based on that returned value but it should only run if that value exists. Here's an example that uses ramda-fantasy implementations of Future & Maybe https://codesandbox.io/s/2xvy3m1qmy

I'm quite possibly getting this whole thing wrong, so if you need more info, or need to change any of the above, go for it. Just to clarify this would be my workflow in pseudo code:

1. Make a request for all values
2. filter values and maybe find one that matches
3. if found, make a request to get the rest of that data

Here's an initial, commented attempt, as linked above:

```
import R from "ramda";
import Fantasy from "ramda-fantasy";
const Future = Fantasy.Future;
const Maybe = Fantasy.Maybe;

// make a fake HTTP request and return a list of values
// response :: Future Array String
const response = Future.of(['one', 'two', 'three'])

const maybeOrNothing = val => val ? Maybe.Just(val) : Maybe.Nothing()

// Maybe return our given value
// getVal :: String -> Maybe String
const getVal = input => response.map(R.find(R.equals(input))).map(maybeOrNothing)

// make another fake request
// let's pretend that this takes an ID and makes a fake ajax request to get teh data
// getValueData :: String -> Future
const getValueData = id => Future((reject, resolve) => {
  // fake HTTP request
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({
      id: id,
      foo: 'bar'
    })
  }, 100)
})

// 'one' should then run getValueData
// something isn't right here, do I need to map then chain?
getVal('one')
.chain(getValueData)
.fork(console.error, console.log)

// 'five' isn't there, so shouldn't run getValueData
// something isn't right here as getValueData still runs
// map(R.chain) works to not run getValueData but then it causes issues later on
getVal('five')
.chain(getValueData)
.fork(console.error, console.log)
```

Comment: Please post the code itself in your question, not just a link to it.

Comment: updated to include code in the post

Comment: `getVal` should have the type `String -> Future (Maybe String)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for the [`sequence` operations](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) that could turn the `Maybe<Future<…>>` into a `Future<Maybe<…>>` which you can then join into your outer future.

With [`traverse`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#traverse):

```
getVal('one')
.chain(traverse(Future.of, getValueData))
.fork(console.error, console.log)
```

Comment: Hey Bergi, thanks for the response, that example didn't quite work. care to elaborate further?

Comment: It definitely should work, however `traverse` always seems to assume a list type not a `Maybe`. I don't know why, you might want to file a Ramda bug.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my own problem, partially because of Bergi's suggestion. Bergi's answer above was very close, but the implementation wasn't quite right. The issue was that I was trying to deal with a Future and then change it to a Maybe, so I dealt with it with the following:

```
import R from "ramda";
import Fantasy from "ramda-fantasy";
const Future = Fantasy.Future;
const Maybe = Fantasy.Maybe;

// make a fake HTTP request and return a list of values
// response :: Future Array String
const response = Future.of(['one', 'two', 'three'])

const maybeOrNothing = val => val ? Maybe.Just(val) : Maybe.Nothing()
const maybeToFuture = m => Maybe.isNothing(m) ? Future.reject() : Future.of(m.value)

// Maybe return our given value
// getVal :: String -> Maybe String
const getVal = input => response.map(R.find(R.equals(input))).map(maybeOrNothing)

// make another fake request
// let's pretend that this takes an ID and makes a fake ajax request to get teh data
// getValueData :: String -> Future
const getValueData = id => Future((reject, resolve) => {
  // fake HTTP request
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({
      id: id,
      foo: 'bar'
    })
  }, 100)
})

// 'one' should then run getValueData
getVal('one')
  .chain(maybeToFuture)
  .chain(getValueData)
  .fork(console.error, console.log)

// five isn't there so getValueData doesn't run
getVal('five')
  .chain(maybeToFuture)
  .chain(getValueData)
  .fork(console.error, console.log)
```

Comment: This doesn't look right, you're not using `Maybe` at all any more. Also your type annotation is wrong now, it should be `getVal :: String -> Future (Future String)`

Comment: added Maybe implementation

Comment: It still converts the `Maybe` to a `Future` (and rejects it!) instead of creating a `Future (Maybe String)` which is what I understood you originally were looking for?

Comment: maybe has a right hand side. either has a right and a left hand side. This implementation of future has a right and a left hand side - this means whenever you have a future you also have the behavior of a maybe (and an either) already available! instead of using maybe.some or maybe.none you can just use future.reject and future.of and avoid doing any transformation between these types. There could be some use to it if you depended on functions that already returned maybes (like maybeFromNothing), but as you're implementing that yourself here anyway, theres no point to using maybe.